# pivot-table and group geometries

Tags: postgresql, sql, pivot-table

Postgresql11 - postgis2.4
Here is a table mytbl with points and an attribute var :

```
geom | var
pt      a
pt      b
pt1     a
pt1     a
pt1     b
pt2     c
...
```

I want to "rotate" the table like this :

```
geom count(a) count(b) count(c)
pt      1       1
pt1     2       1
pt2                      1
...
```

For now I have with...

```
select geom,
 (case when var like 'a' then count(a) end) ,
 (case when var like 'b' then count(b) end) ,
 (case when var like 'c' then count(c) end)
from mytbl
group by geom, var;
```

...the result :

```
geom|count(a)|count(b)|count(c)
pt      1           
pt                  1
pt1     2           
pt1                 1
pt2                         1
....
```

How can I "group again" the features with the same geom to get just one line per geom with all count ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap everything in another query:

```
SELECT * FROM (select ...original query...) GROUP BY geom;
```

But it would be easier to put a [filter clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) on the count:

```
SELECT geom,
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE var = 'a'),
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE var = 'b'),
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE var = 'c')
FROM mytbl
GROUP BY geom;
```

Comment: The FILTER clause is perfect (and new for me). Thanks